# IXpsOMImageResource stream, strange characters while reading

Tags: c++, windows, xaml, xps

I am trying to get Path to file from IXpsOMImageResource.
I know that it has got a stream associated which i get get by calling GetStream()
I do it, but when i try to read from this stream i get strange characters, i really don't know what they mean.

Could anybody help me, to tell me what characters i read from stream.
i don't know mayby those characters are path to file, mayby serialized object. i don't know and i can't find any informations about it

Best regards,
Przemek

Answer (score 0):

The GetStream() method returns a stream that contains the raw image. Depending on the return from the GetImageType() method, this can be a JPEG, PNG, TIFF, or WDP image.

If you want an image file, simply read from this stream and write into a file with the appropriate extension.